# PHP: Using imported class without namespace in class with namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, pear

I'm using a pear library that doesn't utilize namespaces and some composer based libraries which, obviously, do. I'd like to use namespaces in my own code, but I find that when I import classes from the pear library (non-namespaced) I can't reference them correctly.

```
<?php namespace Foo\Bar;

require_once "pearLib/Baz.php";

class MyClass extends Baz { ... }
```

PHP looks for the class `Foo\Bar\Baz`, giving me the message `The Class 'Foo\Bar\DataType' not found`. I simply want the non-namespaced `Baz` class which I just imported. Suggestions???

Comment: `class MyClass extends \Baz`. [Example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php).

Comment: I had tried this before but it caused an error. I realize now that the problem was unrelated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get it off the unanswered list:

---

Use a backslash before the class name like:

```
class MyClass extends \Baz
```